# Can I use Arduino to alert by sound or LED when it detects a certain voltage

Tags: arduino, sensor, voltage-measurement

Can I use a Arduino board to alert me when voltage reaches 2.4v to 2.5v DC?

Can I use a Arduino board to alert me when voltage reaches 0.7 mV sine or co-sine Ac?

Or will I need sensors?

Comment: 5V (which I assume is the full-range of the ADC) divided by 1024 (full range number of steps) gives 4.88 mV / count, which is the best resolution you can attain. So there is no way you can detect a voltage of 0.7 mV without a higher resolution ADC.  You would either need a minimum of a 13-bit ADC (0.61 mV/step), or use an op amp to multiply the signal by at least 10 times so the 0.7 mV is over the 10-bit threshold of 4.88 mV.

Answer (score 7):

The Arduino boards all have multiple ADC pins (analog inputs).

Assuming that the signal voltage to be measured is guaranteed to not exceed the operating voltage of the Arduino (see note below), you can connect the signal directly to one of the ADC pins.

Then, in your Arduino sketch, you can poll the ADC in a loop, reading the ADC value on that pin using `AnalogRead()`, and compare the returned value with the integer value of `(V_trigger / V_operating) * 1023`. Once this value is returned, your code can invoke the appropriate action, such as lighting up an LED.

Most Arduino boards do not have on-board sound devices, so for sound, you *will* need an external speaker, piezo buzzer or similar module. There have been questions on this site and others about output of sound or use of a Piezo buzzer with an Arduino, search and you shall find.

For the Sine or Cosine values, you would need to calculate those in advance, transform to the `AnalogRead()` 0-1023 scale using the computation above, and look for a match for the corresponding `AnalogRead()` value in your code.

Explanation:

The Arduino `AnalogRead()` returns values between 0 and 1023, proportional to the voltage at the ADC pin relative to the operating voltage: For a 5 Volt Arduino, 2.5 Volts at the ADC pin returns `511`.

Issues:

- The ADC value may not be utterly precise due to noise, source voltage impedance, perhaps other factors, hence it might be better to check for a range of values, say 510 to 513 for 2.5 Volts.
- If there is any chance that the voltage to be read might exceed the Arduino's operating voltage, the input signal needs to be scaled down using a voltage divider, and / or clamped to 5 Volts using a zener clamp, or a Schottky diode clamp to the 5V / 3.3V pin. Otherwise the Arduino may be toast.
- If the voltage source you are reading from has high impedance (multiple kOhms), you will need a voltage follower circuit between this source and the Arduino's ADC pin.

---

**Note:**

Operating voltages for Arduino boards:

- `5 Volts` for most older Arduino board designs including the Uno, Mega, Duemilanove etc
- `3.3 Volts` for the Arduino Due, Fio, some Pro and Pro Mini boards, the LilyPad USB and a few clone boards
- `2.7 to 5.5 Volts` for several Lilypad Arduinos and some other clones.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can, but maybe you should take a look at an opamp comparator circuit. It only takes a few components, and is much smaller and cheaper than an Arduino.

Don't ge me wrong, i love Arduino and if you want to use it, go ahead! Nevertheless, it can be very rewarding to do simple tasks without a 'Duino. The comparator circuit really isn't hard to build, and can serve as a stepping stone to more elaborate circuits.

EDIT: MORE INFO ABOUT COMPARATOR CIRCUITS

For an easy to understand example go to http://www.renesas.eu/edge_ol/engineer/03/index.jsp and scroll down to 'Comparator Circuit'.

[image: simple comparator circuit]

Resistor R1 and R2 form a voltage divider, a simple circuit that supplies VREF with a fraction of the power supplies' voltage VDD. Google around for voltage dividers, they're easy to understand. If you replace R1 or R2 with a potmeter, you can adjust VREF's voltage on the fly.

Connect Vout to you LED using a resistor. You can calculate the value of that resistor by using one of the bazillion calculators online. Look around for 'led resistor calculator' or something like that.

Once Vin get's above the threshold set by VREF, the opamp will outputs a voltage as close to its positive power supply voltage as it can. This will light up your LED.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the solution involving a OpAmp comparator circuit? Some schematics maybe?

Comment: Sure thing @Ricardo :)